# Stop resubmit on form

Tags: forms, refresh, submit

I have a simple form on my site that allows users to add comments on photos.  However, the form doenst use ajax (like facebook).  Instead, it submits the form and refreshes the page.  This is fine however, if a user reloads the page, there is an alert that he/she will resubmit the data resulting in two of the same comments.  Id like to remove this resubmit without sending the user to a confirmation page.  Thanks.

Here is my form:

```
<form name='form' action='index.php' method='POST'>
<input type='text' name='comment'>
<input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'>
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $comment=$_POST[comment];
        $time=time();
             $id=$_GET['id'];
         $put=mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('','$user','$time','$comment','$id')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP script simply re-rendering the page in response to a form post? The standard way to get the behavior you describe is that it should either return a HTTP status of 204 (No content) or 303 (see other, with a redirect to the page you want to show).

Comment: Hey.  Sorry im a noob so i dont really understand.  But my php code is now updated in my initial question.  thanks

Comment: That PHP is something you do _in addition_ to producing HTML for the page right? You need to figure out how to make PHP produce a specific HTTP response code _instead of_ serving a HTML page in response to the form data from the browser.